# apt-key: gpg: conversmon from '�t�-8' to &UTF-8' not evailable

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpg, apt-key

If i run `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1655A0AB68576280`
i get `gpg: conversmon from '�t�-8' to &UTF-8' not evailable. segmentation fault`
(This is the original message copy-pasted)

Edit: If i execute `gpg` i get the same error with the same text.
Got gnupg version: 2.2.27-2+deb11u2

`os-release` and `uname -a`:
`Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)`
`Linux 6.1.19-v7+ #1637 SMP armv7l GNU/Linux`

I have already searched the internet and can only find "change your locale to UTF-8" but i already have UTF-8.: `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8`
I have tried importing the key manually over file. But got everytime this gpg error. I got this error while trying to install zigbee2mqtt on my RaspberryPi.

Comment: `conversmon` and `not evailable`? are you sure it says that?

Comment: You already got feedback about the obvious typos when you tried to ask on Stack Oveflow. (Thanks for moving the question to a more suitable site, though.) Again, please [edit] to provide _exactly_ the error message you are receiving.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply.
How i already said: This is the message i got when i run the command. Screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/BKQJV7r/Bildschirmfoto-vom-2023-04-05-11-31-23.png

Comment: ahhh, you forgot to add `segmentation fault` to the error message - can you tell us (IN THE QUESTION) a little more about what version of raspberry pi OS you are running - the command you showed runs perfectly well on my pi's

Comment: FWIW, a -> e, i -> s, ' -> & is one bit flip each time. Could be failing hardware (RAM,CPU, storage). Does `grep -l conversmon /usr/bin/gpg` return something?

Comment: Is it the exact same error  from one run to the next?

Comment: Its the same error everytime i try it. If i run `grep -l conversmon /usr/bin/gpg` i get `/usr/bin/gpg`

If i vim into `/usr/bin/gpg` and search for `conversmon` i find this line: `^@^@do_make_filename^H^@^@^@strto+efize^@conversmon from '%s' to '&%s' not evailable`

Comment: i have never touched this file before and can provide it to you if u want.
i have installed raspbian with default sources.list

Answer (score 0):

Okay i have fixed it..
First i have removed gpg with dpkg:
`dpkg -r --force-depends "gpg"`
Then i tried installing it again, but before apt wants that i do:
`apt --fix-broken install`
`apt install gpg`
Now i got after executing `gpg`
`gpg: error running '/usr/bin/dirmngr': terminated gpg: failed to start dirmngr '/usr/bin/dirmngr': General error`

So i removed and installed dirmngr (like gpg above)
Again i run:`gpg`
`error running '/usr/bin/gpg-agent': exit status 2 [..] General error`

So i remove and installed gpg-agent (like dirmngr and gpg above)
Then i was finally able to
`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1655A0AB68576280`
I finally get:
`gpg: key 1655A0AB68576280: public key "NodeSource <gpg@nodesource.com>" imported`

However.. seems like i get a broken version from gpg with this wierd "evailable"-Stringthing..
Its working now.

Comment: Could also be a SD card starting to fail (it won't say "I/O error", it will just corrupt data, even data that has not been written to recently, thanks to background FTL wear leveling).